# How to create notification system in rails with 2 different type of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating rails application using gem https://github.com/rails-engine/notifications for my notification system. The docs giving an example to create notification system with some generators to create views, controller, model, routes etc. But, its only for one user. I want to create notifications for two type of users, lets say student and teacher. how do i configure notification for the second user since the docs only giving an example for one user?

Comment: It is creating a notification for any user object passed so it should work for any number of users. If you want to create it for `n` users then iterating over `n` users and passing each of the them to create a notification should work. You should be a little more specific about the actual problem you are facing.

Comment: @AlokSwain i mean, i have two types of user like student and teacher. i think the table of notifications must be seperated. how about that?

Comment: Who creates the notification for Student and Teacher ? Name of the model ? Can you explain more ? To make a same model work for other models you can make it polymorhic.. i.e. in app/models/notification.rb -> `belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true`
In student.rb and teacher,rb `has_many :notifications, as: :notifiable` 
And modify the migration of the notification to include both the values. P.S this is a guideline to achieve something like that; I would encourage you to try the gem out and also read its source code more to explore what all it provides and how you can best use it.

Comment: Do Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example